# How to handle empty strings in JSON data through an Overlay Type

Tags: java, javascript, json, gwt

I've managed to get an array of JavaScriptObjects but sometimes an object's field has an empty string in it, when it should be a double.

My methods in my overlay type are similar to these.

```
//JSNI methods to get stock data.
 public final native double getPrice() /*-{ return this.price; }-*/;
 public final native double getChange() /*-{ return this.change; }-*/;
```

If the field is indeed a double then the JavaScriptObject returns it.

When I call getPrice() on a JavaScriptObject when there is an empty string field I get a exception.

How and where should I handle this?

Example Data:
    {
      "Year" : 1881,
      "Annual Mean" : -0.2,
      "5 yr Mean" : ""
    },
    {
      "Year" : 1882,
      "Annual Mean" : -0.26,
      "5 yr Mean" : -0.27
    },

Note: This part of my program is based heavily on

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's an empty string `""`, then it can't be converted into a `double` type. You have got to handle it in your JSNI method (obviously it's up to you to decide what you want to return from the `getXXX()` method if the JSON value is `""`, but let's assume you want to return 0. Then your getter should look like this:

```
public final native double getPrice() /*-{ return this.price === "" ? 0 : this.price; }-*/;
```

Comment: Because empty strings evaluate to false when coerced to booleans, you can also use `return this.price || 0`